# jenkins execute shell over ssh hangs when using "sudo su"

Tags: jenkins, ssh

The field `Exec command` of `execute shell over ssh`, I only put command `sudo su` in there.

But when I build the project, it always stop at the command `sudo su` till timeout.

[The image show what I get in console output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsnjI.png)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

## sudo

sudo is used for custom installations, system files modification, etc

## Interactive shells (human in front of monitor)

When you exec some command preceded by **sudo**, this shell will ask you for the password of some privileged user. This ask event **waits** for user response:

[image]

## Background executions

Some process, crons, scripts or applications like jenkins needs to execute **sudo** commands. But in this mode , there is no way to enter the password. This is the reason of your **timeout**

## Solutions

- disable requiretty

  https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/1adaaa07885b45d497b519431701a943

  Security risk of this approach:

  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65789/188975
- use a pseudo TTY in Jenkins

  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373843/188975

  [image]

Comment: I tried disable requiretty and also checked Exec In pty, but still get the same result.

Comment: Is the same log?

Comment: Yes, same as the image(console output).

Comment: By the way, my account was belong a group which gain root privileges. So it will not ask me for the password.

Comment: Try this : `ssh username@remote_ip 'sudo free -m'` using  your credentials direct on your shell (without jenkins) in order to verify if your tty configurations are correct.

Comment: I try the command and it show memory usage properly.
[execute result](https://i.imgur.com/F3bmkPj.png)

Comment: mmm . Which user do you connect with for this test? Also, how are your executing this command with jenkins? Be precise ;)

Comment: The connecting user of test is same in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/F3bmkPj.png). With Jenkins, I put command in `Exec command` field of `Build` section as [image](https://i.imgur.com/VHKuThk.png) and the result of execution show as this [image](https://i.imgur.com/lmPLo0f.png)

Comment: In your third image : https://i.imgur.com/lmPLo0f.png, I can see a success execution of sudo command with your Jenkins. Is not that what you needed?

Comment: If I use command `sudo su` in Jenkins. The console will hangs and till timeout like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Ipff0iF.png).

Comment: **sudo su** command will ask you for password. If your current user has correct privilegies, you just need **sudo** instead **sudo su**

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the expect directive.

Comment: What does that mean?